# How to get data for specific user, but from different table

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I want to display the data for user 1 from database A right after he logged in, right now the page showing all the data from the table.

currently I have 2 table which is for **user login** and **user transaction**. so after they logged in, i want them to be able to view their own record. After do searching, im thinking that it has something to do with session.

can someone help me?

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "";
$mysl_database = "mockup";

$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
mysql_select_db($mysl_database, $conn);
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user
        WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numRows==1) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["ID"] = $ID;
    header("Location: ./profile_page.php");
} else {
    echo "Invalid Login Information";   
}
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>User Name</td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**profile_page.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); // start the session
include("connection.php");

$ID = $_SESSION["ID"]; // store the user id into session

$sql = "SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE ID='$ID'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$deposit = $row["deposit"];


echo "
<table>
    <tr><td>transaction</td><td> : </td><td>$transaction</td></tr>

</table>
";
}
?>
```

Comment: You can store the userid in session and then from that userid you can easily get the data of logged in user from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connection.php

```
<?php
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_pass = "";
$mysl_database = "database_name";

$conn = mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass);
mysql_select_db($mysl_database, $conn);
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user
            WHERE username='$username' AND pass='$pass'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numRows==1) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["userid"] = $userid;
        header("Location: ./profile_page.php");
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Login Information";   
    }
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>User Name</td><td><input type="text" name="username" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="pass" /></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

profile_page.php

```
<?php
session_start(); // start the session
include("connection.php");

$user_id = $_SESSION["userid"]; // store the user id into session

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $username = $row["username"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $email = $row["email"];

    echo "
    <table>
        <tr><td>User Name</td><td> : </td><td>$username</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Name</td><td> : </td><td>$name</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email</td><td> : </td><td>$email</td></tr>
    </table>
    ";
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks or your responds, but what does <?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?> do??

Comment: Script name is absolute path to file.

Comment: i see, i try using your code with my database, and it goes to profile_page.php, but it deos not come out with any result, just a blank page. Do I need to set anything on my tables in database?

Comment: You have to set database name and other information in connection.php file.
In profile_page.php, you have to set your table name and according to table_name set field name.

Comment: yeah, i already did that, but do i need to set in column ID to primary key or something?

Comment: User id must be unique. So that you have to give primary key to each user's id.

Comment: in profile_page.php
there shold be:
echo "
<table>
    <tr><td>transaction</td><td> : </td><td>$deposit</td></tr>

</table>
";

Comment: replacing echo "
<table>
    <tr><td>transaction</td><td> : </td><td>$transaction</td></tr>

</table>
";       ??

Comment: i replace them, but the result is the same,

Comment: can you check that which data are going to displaying in query.??

Comment: suppose that the deposit data will come out from table transaction.

Answer (score 0):

you can protect and access the user data after they logged in sucessfully by the help of session.

you could use `session_start()` for start new session or resume existing session.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['user_sesion_variable']))
  {
    header("location:login.php");
   die();
}
// here go your user database value
```